# How to implement a "Don't show this message again"

Tags: asp.net, jquery, .net-3.5

In a ASP.NET/JQuery/.NET 3.5 environment, how would I show a `DIV` with a "Don't show this message again" option when clicked will not show the `DIV` to the user.

I would need to do it in 2 different scenarios - 1 with authenticated users and the other with anonymous users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used [jquery cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) plugin to set a cookie and read it before i show the dialog

**EXAMPLE:** with a little bonus function

```
  if ($.cookie("warned") != "warned"){
    display_alert("WARNING: This diallog will not appear again until your next session");
    $.cookie('warned', 'warned', { expires: 0 }); 
  }

  function display_alert(message,title) {
    title = title || "Alert";
      $('#alert').text(message);

      $("#alert").dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          bgiframe: true,
          modal: true,
        title:title,
          buttons: {
              OK: function() {
                  $(this).dialog('close');
              }
          }
      });
    $('#alert').dialog('option', 'title', title);
      $("#alert").dialog('open');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For authenticated users you could use a flag in the database and for anonymous users you could use a cookie.

Answer (score -1):

Matt Berseth had a very informative post on how to do this for delete confirmation. However this solution will only work for authenticated users.  For anonymous users you will probably have to do something client-side (a cookie?). I used his solution in my own application.

Comment: This requires me to use ASP.NET profiles. I'd rather not use it if its not necessary

Comment: link gone. this why it's best to copy relevant bits into stackoverflow